# wso2 uses an unsupported protocol

Tags: amazon-ec2, wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have set up an WSO2 Identity server in an EC2 instance. I have mapped the carbon.xml entries to this EC2 instance. The WSO2 server is starting up in that IP without any errors.But when i access it , i get a strange SSL error .ideally SSL warning should be coming since i am using WSO2 provided certificates itself and i can go on bypassing it.This is for sample environment so i am not planning to buy certificates
But this error is totally different and there is no way to bypass it.
The error in chrome says

```
50.200.189.207 uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
Unsupported protocol
The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.
```

I am unable to get rid of this.What could be the cause?

Comment: What's your chrome version and openssl version?

Comment: Are u running on open jdk? This issue can occur if you run on open jdk. Please use oracle jdk - https://docs.wso2.com/display/compatibility/Tested+Operating+Systems+and+JDKs

Comment: But i have done the same with other machines which has Open JDK..those machines doesnt have this issue.What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some environments may have (mis)configured already unsupported ciphers (I had this issue on AWS Linux with OpenJDK as well, not on CentOS with Oracle JDK).

I suggest you to read [WSO2 CARBON Configuring TLS](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Configuring+Transport+Level+Security)

long story short:

1. open $WSO2IS/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml
2. Locate Connector for TLS (port 9443 with sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" )
3. add property: ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"

note: please read the documentation for exact values of the cipher property

And indeed, Oracle JDK is recommended for WSO2 products (as noted in the comments), the JDK vendors may differ in supported ciphers

If it doesn't work, let me know, I will post exactly what I've used for other projects